# May I know why can't I combine the vertical values to horizontal values , whereas it keeps giving me the last value of the generated value

Tags: python, python-3.x

May I know what went wrong here please ! Thank You !

```
import random
import string

pattern = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*'
key = ''

for i in range(10):
    password = random.choice(pattern)
    key = ''.join(password)

print(key)
```

Comment: I did got my solution by using { key+=password } , however I'm just curious why mine didn't work out whereas so many other coders out there manage to do it . Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `join()` both the previous `key` and the `password`.

```
import random 
import string

pattern = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*' 
key = ''

for i in range(10): 
    password = random.choice(pattern) 
    key = ''.join((key, password))  # key = ''.join(password) 
    print(password)

print(key)
```

Output:

```
R
G
A
D
z
C
v
B
M
s
RGADzCvBMs
```

Comment: Thank You ! However I'm quite confused y do I have to join in the key() in the join function . As the program is just to combine all the vertical letters , and since it is also assigned to key { key = ''.join(password) } in this line . I'm sorry if I'm asking a dump  question ..

Comment: @Cobralim not a dumb question. The function `str.join(...)` of any string basically takes as parameters a list of strings, and combines them together with that string in between. So by using `''.join((key, password))`, you are saying 'combine `key` and `password` together with and empty string in between. If you use `''.join(password)`, you are kinda saying "combine the characters in the string variable `password`"

Comment: Thank you so much ! That made my understanding boost like a hundred times ! thank you :)